# If statement not working in Android OnClick

Tags: java, android, if-statement, onclick

I am new to Android Studio. In my project, I am trying to use IF statement in a very simple setting (to activate a change) but it doesn't work. Your help will be greatly appreciated. Below is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button mBtLaunchActivity;
    private Button Home;
    int a = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_button);

        mBtLaunchActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.map_button);

        mBtLaunchActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                launchActivity();
                a = 1;
            }

        });

    }

    private void launchActivity() {

        if (a == 1) {
            Home.setVisibility(View.INVISBLE);
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are updating `value` of `a` after launch of `Activity`.That will never work.

Update it before it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    launchActivity();
    a = 1;

}
```

Change it:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    a = 1;
    launchActivity();


}
```